# Is there a way to send delayed emails from salesforce

Tags: email, administration

I wanted check if it all its possible to send delayed emails from salesforce. ie. I want my sales people to be able to send emails to customers on future dates. Is this possible ?

The only thing i could come up is this idea
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007o7HAAQ

If somebody has a workaround,  i would love to hear it even if it means a little apex/process builder.

Thanks

Comment: You can always set up time-based workflow rules.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Not really.. it doesnt really happen after x days it should be something which the user can choose the dates

Comment: is apex scheduler an option for you? In here you can specified a specific datetime in the future to execute the action (apex class to send an email). The only problem is that required some coding. One VF and apex class but whit this should be enough.

Comment: You can use time-based workflow by setting it to run 0 days after the date is reached if you store the date as a field against the record. That way the user can select the date and the WF will fire.

Comment: @RichardDurrant   Oh great thats a good option. Let me try that

Comment: @RichardDurrant Which object do you associate the workflow with? Send email in salesforce i understand creates an Task. Are you suggesting some other way?

Comment: @Prady - Associate the WF with whatever object type you need it on. Just add an email alert to the TBWF and you're good to go.

Comment: @RichardDurrant. I would urge you to convert your comments to an answer to help preserve them in a form that will make it easy for others to find, especially if a few more details are provided. Excellent solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use time-based workflow by setting it to run 0 days after the date is reached if you store the date as a field against the record. That way the user can select the date and the WF will fire.

Associate the WF with whatever object type you need it on. Just add an email alert to the TBWF and you're good to go.

Also check out process builder for the functionality in there - its like workflow, but on steroids.